Remove default space made by p tag
I'm trying to remove the default space that appears at the start of a paragraph. Is there a CSS property like 'paragraph-spacing' that can help with this?
I tried using 'paragraph-spacing' from another website, but VS Code didn't recognize it, and it didn't work on my webpage either. How can I fix this?

What spacing in particular, a text-indent, a line-break between the <p> and a previous element, something else? When you say you "tried using the paragraph-spacing that [you saw elsewhere]" what does that mean, what CSS, HTML, JavaScript, or other code did you try to use? In what way did it fail, you say it "[didn't] recognise the property" but how do you know, what did you see instead?

Are you using your browser devtools inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied, and from where it comes. From you description it sounds as though you are talking about some default settings from the browser but it's difficult to tell.

Paragraph tags include paragraph spacing. If you don't want to use it you could manually set the margin and padding to 0 !important, or just use <span> tags instead.
